# How to extract the name of a file when even my path is not known?

Tags: c++

I will be using a file loaded in a USB to update my system and this file will change its name based on the version released. Said that, I know just part of the path i.e. /run/media/update_1.1.tar

SO how can I:
1 - handle a path that will change
2 - how can I extract just the version number from that path?

Thanks

Comment: What is stopping you from simply iterating the files in the `/run/media/` folder on the USB, comparing each file name to see if it starts with `"update_"`, and when you find a match than copying the version number from the end of it?  What have you tried so far to implement this, and what is the actual problem you are having with it?

Comment: 1: My lack of experience with c++. 2: I need to have the full name to add to the path to run the command to extract the file

Comment: Well, I already outlined the various steps you need in my last comment. That is how you solve things - break down tasks into smaller steps. Have a look at  [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator), [`std::string::compare()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare). and [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much! doing it right now

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am not sure why but I am not able to use filesystem. I am working on QtCreator and added the experimental/filesystem and still couldnt use it. Any idea?

Comment: Not with that limited information. But there are many other ways to iterate the contents of a directory, such as using platforms APIs like `opendir()`+`readdir()` on 'Nix, or `FindFirstFile()`+`FindNextFile()` on Windows, etc

Comment: I am working on Qt creator with Linux not windows. Today the function we have is something like if (exists (" /run/media/update.tar)) do something... but as I commented before, now, my file will be update_1.0.1.tar, so I need to find the correct path to use on the existent function.

Comment: I already told you how to find that. You said you are having problems implementing that, but you didn't say what those problems actually are. So how do you expect to get help with it? You need to be more specific.

Comment: I tried to run the example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator and my compiler says "filesystem is not a namespace-name"

Comment: Do you have `#include <filesystem>`?  Are you using a compiler that supports C++17 **and** has it enabled? Many modern compilers require you to explicitly request C++11 or later via a command line switch or in a makefile.